# Associative Array + Foreach statement -- undefined variable

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm really struggling with making this work, I have looked at guides but I can't seem to see the difference between mine and theirs, other than how the array is laid out.

```
<?php
$country = array('England' => "London", 'Scotland' => "Edinburgh", 'France' => "Paris");

foreach ($capitals as $country=>$capital) {
echo "The capital of $country is $capital";
}

?>
```

All I want it to do is say the country and its capital.

error code --

```
Notice: Undefined variable: capitals in C:\xampp\htdocs\foreach.php on line 4

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\foreach.php on line 4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, where did you define `$capitals`? I don't see it anywhere. I guess you want to use `$capitals = array(...);` instead of `$country = array(...);`.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could at least include the example shown in the guide for comparison.  Saying "I've been looking at guides" doesn't tell us which guide.

Comment: Which part of `Undefined variable: capitals` don't you understand? (that's a serious question, I'm not being condescending, just don't know how to phrase it better). It gives a pretty clear signal what is wrong, namely that you are trying to access a variable that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to this:

(I change the array name from `country` to `capitals`)

```
<?php

    $capitals = array('England' => "London", 'Scotland' => "Edinburgh", 'France' => "Paris");

    foreach ($capitals as $country=>$capital) {
        echo "The capital of $country is $capital<br />";
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
The capital of England is London
The capital of Scotland is Edinburgh
The capital of France is Paris
```

Comment: What did you change and why?

Comment: @FelixKling I change the array name from: `country` to `capitals`, because OP just named the array wrong.

Comment: Thanks I knew it would be a small change that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to loop through an array, `$capitals`, that doesn't exist. You have to loop through the array `$country`.

```
foreach ($country as $country=>$capital) {
    echo "The capital of $country is $capital";
}
```

Comment: Will there be any problems with naming the loop variable `$country` as well?

Comment: In [testing](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/08yc-ru4z) it works just fine. It isn't good style, but it works @FelixKling

Comment: Only if you don't want to access the array after the loop: http://codepad.org/2KxU6ACH

Comment: True @FelixKling - my answer was more about looping through something that didn't exist.